# Hyperlinks show in the wrong place

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

In my `TextView`, I have two hyperlinks that I want to show them after a bullet. However, the two bullets show, but both links are showing after the second bullet, while I coded one of them on the first.

This is an image of how it looks like, I just want the first or second link on the first bullet.
[Clik here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwEzx.png)

Every kind of help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**This is my `strings.xml` code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Rodekruis</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_nieuws">NieuwsActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_afspraak"><b>Afspraak</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Maken en wijzigen</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Zelf uw afspraak maken of wijzigen? Dat kan, mits us al als patiënt geregistreerd staat bij het RKZ. Is dit nog niet het geval? Dan wordt de afspraak telefonish gepland. Meer info&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Bekijk ook</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/eerste_polikliniekbezoek'> &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</a>&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/wachttijden'> </a></string>
    <string name="title_activity_bezoek"><b>Bezoektijden</b>\n\nVrijwel iedere patiënt vindt het prettig bezoek te ontvangen. Onze ervaring is
    dat een goed contact met vrienden en familie een bijdrage kan leveren aan 
    een spoedig herstel.\n\nVoor de meeste afdelingen gelden de volgende bezoektijden:\nvan 15.15 tot 16.15 uur;\nvan 19.00 tot 20.00 uur.\n\nLet op: tijdens feestdagen gelden in het RKZ andere bezoektijden dan normaal.
    Bekijk de website voor uitgebreide bezoektijden.</string>
    <string name="title_activity_contact">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Contact</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Telefoon en internet Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5555 (algemeen nummer, ook Poli IJmuiden)&lt;br /&gt;www.rkz.nl<a href='https://www.rkz.nl'> </a>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Huisartsenpost Midden-Kennemerland (begane grond RKZ)&lt;br /&gt;Voor huisartsenzorg buiten kantooruren&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5265&lt;br /&gt;
    (A.u.b. bellen voordat u langskomt)&lt;br /&gt; Spoedeisende Hulp RKZ en Huisartsenpost: meer informatie&lt;br /&gt;Bij levensbedreigende klachten belt u altijd 112&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bezoek- en postadres Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;Route(link)&lt;br /&gt;Postbus 1074&lt;br /&gt;1940 EB Beverwijk</string>
    <string name="title_activity_mening">MeningActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_route">\n\n\n\n<b>Route</b>\n\nRode Kruis Ziekenhuis, hoofdgebouw\nVondellaan 13\n1942 LE Beverwijk\n\nDe Velsertunnel is van medio mei tot eind 2016 gesloten.\nVoor verkeer vanuit zuidelijke richting is het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk hierdoor moeilijker bereikbaar. Bekijk: \n\n\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie korte routes naar/van het RKZ\n\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie langere routers naar/van het RKZ\n\u2022    plan uw route naar/van het RKZ met      actuele verkeersinformatie\n\nRKZ Poli IJmuiden (tijdelijk i.v.m. sluiting Velsertunnel)\nGezondheidscentrum Het Plein\nPlein 1945, nr.1\nIJmuiden\n\u2022    Plan uw route(Google maps)\n\u2022    Meer informatie over de Poli IJmuiden</string>
    <string name="title_activity_specialisten">SpecialistenActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_bwc">  &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Brandwondencentrum</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Het RKZ Brandwondencentrum, beter bekend als: Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk, levert al meer dan veertig jaar topklinische zorg op het gebied van huid-, brandwonden- en littekenbehandelingen en wordt zowel in het binnen- als buitenland hoog gewaardeerd.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Wie werken er in het Brandwondencentrum? Wat maakt het centrum zo bijzonder? Wat is een brandwond precies, wanneer is behandeling in het Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk nodig? Welke behandelingen vinden er plaats? Hoe vindt een opname plaats en wat zijn de bezoekregels? En welke afdelingen en poliklinieken behoren tot het brandwondencentrum?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van Brandwondencentrum worden deze vragen uitegebreid beantwoord.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk heeft speciaal voor kinderen en tieners een <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> </a></string>
    <string name="title_activity_agenda">AgendaActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_informatie"><b>Welkom op de RKZ app!</b>\n\nU heeft de app gedownload van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk. Met onze app geven wij u beknopte, praktische informatie over ons ziekenhuis die u deels offline (zonder internet) kunt raadplegen.\n\nVoor vervolginformatie verwijzen wij u via links naar onze website. Hiervoor heeft u internet nodig.\n\nBent u in het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis, dan kunt u gebruik maken van gratis Wifi (draadloos internet). Hoe werkt het?\n\n\u2022   Ga naar de WiFi-instellingen op uw mobiele apparaat.\n\u2022   Maak verbinding met het netwerk <b>RKZ_Bezoekers.</b>\n\u2022    Open uw internetbrowser (zoals Internet, Explorer, Firefox of Safari)\n\u2022   U komt automatisch op de portal van het RKZ. Wilt u gebruik maken van Wifi in het RKZ, dan klikt u hier op <u>akkoord</u> om de voorwaarden te accepteren.\n\u2022   De browser verwijst u door naar de pagina http://www.rkz.nl.</string>
    <string name="title_activity_vriend">\n\n\n\n<b>Word vriend van het RKZ</b>\n\nEen verblijf in het ziekenhuis is meestal niet erg plezierig. De Stichting Vrienden van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis spant zich in om het verblijf van patiënten, bezoekers en medewerkers van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis en het bijbehorende Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk te veraangenamen. Door geld in te zamelen voor voorzieningen die niet uit het basisbudget van het ziekenhuis kunnen worden betaald. Denk aan een opknapbeurt voor de speelkamer voor jonge patiënten of een verwenbehandeling bij een chemokuur.\n\nOok u kunt helpen. Door Vriend te worden van het RKZ of door ons eenmalig te steunen. Lees verder op de website.\n\nMet vrienden om je heen voel je je beter. Geef om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis.</string>
    <string name="title_activity_folders">FoldersActivity</string>

</resources>
```

**This is my main activity code:**

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AfspraakActivity extends Activity {


    TextView HyperLink;
    Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_afspraak);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_afspraak);
        text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/eerste_polikliniekbezoek'> Wat neem ik mee naar een eerste afspraak?</a>\n\n";
        text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/wachttijden'> Wat zijn de wachttijden?</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


    }

}
```

> EDIT : 1

**This is my activity_xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Afspraak" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/btn_informatie" />
 </FrameLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_afspraak"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your `activity_afspraak.xml`

Comment: i've added it. see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDIT 1:**

**Use `<br/>` instead of `\n`:**

```
text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/eerste_polikliniekbezoek'> Wat neem ik mee naar een eerste afspraak?</a><br/><br/>";

// I have added \u2022 here for second Bullet.

text += " \u2022 <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/wachttijden'> Wat zijn de wachttijden?</a>";
```

Modify your string like this :

```
<string name="title_activity_afspraak"><b>Afspraak</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Maken en wijzigen</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Zelf uw afspraak maken of wijzigen? Dat kan, mits us al als patiënt geregistreerd staat bij het RKZ. Is dit nog niet het geval? Dan wordt de afspraak telefonish gepland. Meer info&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Bekijk ook</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022 </string> 

// At last there is a \u2022 for First Bullet
```

Because there is no meaning of adding `<a>` in string.xml.

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: What happened now is that the first link is showing next to the second bullet. The second like is not visible anymore. Do you know how to put the first link to the first bullet, and the second to the second? Thanks for the effort already.

Comment: and dw if your answer ends up working i'll accept yours.

Comment: what are that bullets actually?? i mean how they came there ?? i can not see them in your layout..!!

Comment: \u2022 in strings.xml makes the bullets appear. I have them in front of my link there

Comment: My Pleasure.. Upvoting the answer will be a favor :)

Comment: Did it, don't have 15 points or something yet, so it won't show.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using HTML so use **`<br>`** instead of **`\n`**

As **\n** does not work in HTML

Use

```
text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/eerste_polikliniekbezoek'> Wat neem ik mee naar een eerste afspraak?</a><br/><br/>";
text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/wachttijden'> Wat zijn de wachttijden?</a>";
```

If you really want to use `\n` you should use `content-type: text/plain` but then you'll lose any markup.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   // set this to wrap_content
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_afspraak"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: what a great answer.. simply copy pasting and change some english..!!

Comment: What happened now is that the first link is showing next to the second bullet. The second like is not visible anymore. Do you know how to put the first link to the first bullet, and the second to the second? Thanks for the effort already.

Comment: This makes the second link appear in the bottom of the screen. That link is now just open, first link is still behind the first bullet. They both need to go upwards one place, the first bullet is just showing nothing now.

Comment: Use one <br> instead of two

Comment: Can you please post the image how it is coming right now. Also post the image who you want to appear this layout by drawing on paper

Comment: You don't understand. There is nothing behind the first bullet. Both links are after the second bullet, deleting 1 of the 2 br's just makes the second link go a bit closer to the first, but they're still behind the second bullet. I need them both to go upwards so the first link comes after the first bullet, second after the second.